# How might one print the \tt prime character while in taocpmac's begintt mode?

Tags: plain-tex, typewriter

I am using `\begintt` and `\endtt` from Knuth's `taocpmac.tex` and I would like to typeset the prime character, not the apostrophe. My code looks something like this:

```tex
\input taocpmac

\begintt
a' = a + 1
\endtt

\bye
```

The escape character in this mode is switched to `|` but I can't figure out what command to use. The glyph exists in computer modern tt (glyph number 411) so how do I access it?

Comment: Have you tried either `$\tt a' = a + 1$` or `a$\tt'$ = a + 1`? The math-mode "prime" glyph will take up less space than the text-mode "apostrophe" glyph, for sure.

Comment: Sorry there's a lot more verbatim code than my example so I can't just do it in math mode.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Maybe just `|char 411`? I don't have that tex file though.

Comment: What do you mean by “glyph number 411”? As far as I know Computer Modern Mono has just 128 glyphs. Are you using XeTeX or LuaTeX? If so, what monospaced font are you employing?

Comment: In Knuth's books, I think he *deliberately* uses a glyph that looks like an apostrophe, because the character you type for a prime in maths *is* the apostrophe character (ASCII 39).  Assuming you are using plain `cmtt10` as the font for your code then I think you'll find something that looks like a straight single quote as char 13, so you could try `|char13 `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To follow up on @Thruston's comment: If what you're looking to get is a straight/vertical apostrophe character instead of what's produced by `'`, `\char13` should be the way to go.

[image]

```
\obeylines
\tt
a' = a + 1 
a\char39{} = a + 1
a\char13{} = a + 1
\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want that `'` produces the straigh quote that lives at slot 13 of `cmtt10`.

```
\input taocpmac

% a helper macro
\def\activequote{\begingroup
  \lccode`~=`'\lowercase{\endgroup\chardef~}13
  \catcode`'=\active}
% add to \ttverbatim
\expandafter\def\expandafter\ttverbatim\expandafter{\ttverbatim\activequote}

\begintt
a' = a + 1
\endtt

\bye
```

[image]

What does this code do?

1. `\activequote` makes the active quote to produce the character at slot 13 in the current font and activates the quote
2. `\activequote` is added at the end of the replacement text of `\ttverbatim`

An equivalent redefinition of `\ttverbatim` would be

```
\toks0=\expandafter{\ttverbatim\activequote}
\edef\ttverbatim{\the\toks0}
```